Jewish Halacha or Hashkafa WhatsApp groups
Does anyone know of Jewish related, Halacha, Hashkafa WhatsApp groups?

https://chat.whatsapp.com/GUkXkOpwyfq3DU6epQlRZJ

https://chat.whatsapp.com/IWKTT4T6CN8JAVMvw1Ol1d Best one

https://chat.whatsapp.com/GFRNDpSWoFHGhHYziqAGYv

Here's a Halacha WhatsApp group link .
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=https://halachayomit.co.il/he/Default.aspx?HalachaID=4382
Here's a WhatsApp group link discussing different Kosher breweries
https://chat.whatsapp.com/DY3xk9fZp8ZKBLw41GZMdu
Here's an informative group for Kashrus discussions.
https://chat.whatsapp.com/DFn0U662ksGGAHV3vkKEl5
Here's a whatsapp link of many different types of learning styles and options
https://machshevesyechezkel.com
Here's an open discussion group about Judiasm and everything in between.
https://chat.whatsapp.com/F3E6TUq5Ijc5QrTQFgWRdp
Here's a link to an interesting one second shiur
https://chat.whatsapp.com/KDx9xy8vxPRC4fAWzoOYQU

seeker I'm interested in the brewery and kashrut link. But the link is dead. Can you resend?

Here's a different one. https://chat.whatsapp.com/DFn0U662ksGGAHV3vkKEl5

Also not working...

https://chat.whatsapp.com/FX0umIY9MNv12hDVjWb3RL

That works. ThanQ
